What's the probability that the student answers correctly, if the probability of them knowing and eliminating an answer are 50% and 25% respectively
This is a problem from my probability exam. I've found many similar problems and variations of it but not one like this where the person has a certain chance to eliminate the problem and the probabilities are given. Also I'd like to know if and why my specific reasoning is wrong.

Jerry is attending a test and each question has $4$ answers to choose from, and only $1$ answer is correct.
He spent the exact amount of time studying needed to guarantee that he knows the answer to the question with the probability of $50\%$.
Also, the probability that he'll correctly eliminate one answer is $25\%$.
Otherwise, he is guessing from the $4$ offered answers, or from $3$ if he already eliminated one.


(a) What's the probability that Jerry answers a question correctly?


(b) What's the probability that Jerry knows the answer to the question, given that he answered it correctly?

Let $C, K, E$ be events that he answers correctly, that he knows the answer, and that he eliminates the answer, respectively.
For (a), we are asked to find $P(C)$, while the probabilities of other two events occurring are $P(K)=0.5$ and $P(E)=0.25$, which makes the probabilities of their complements $P(K^{\complement}) = 0.5$ and $P(E^{\complement}) = 0.75$.
The way I reasoned through this problem is illustrated in the image below: the green branch gives the $P(C|K)=0.5$, the orange branch gives $P(C|K^{\complement} \cap E)=1/3 \cdot 0.5$ and the red branch gives $P(C|K^{\complement} \cap E^{\complement}) = 1/4 \cdot 0.5$, and the sum of all of the branches would be the asked probability $P(C)\approx 0.791$.
So for the green branch it makes sense to me for the probability to be $0.5$ but it doesn't make sense that P(C|K)=0.5, I think it should be P(C|K)=1, which is absurd in this framing. So I guess something's wrong there. For the orange branch, my reasoning was that if we eliminate one answer we have a $1/3$ chance of answering correctly, and similarly for the red branch, the chance is $1/4$. Is the problem framed correctly like this? Obviously this is an improvised solution, but I'd like to know what would the standard procedure of solving this problem look like. What I did looks to me like using the Law of Total Probability (LoTP) , but when I try to use LoTP explicitly I fail to do so.
Edit$_1$: ok as usual I come to understand things after posting the question: I guess we use LoTP twice: once at the top level of the tree and here the complete system of events is made of $K$ and $K^{\complement}$, and second time when we enter the $K^{\complement}$ branch, here the complete system of events is made of $E$ and $E^{\complement}$ &mdash : Does this make sense?
Edit$_2$: reasoning like this, then the probability for the green branch is actually $P(K)P(C|K)=0.5 \cdot 1=0.5$ which checks out with my intuition, and resolves all my issues here, if it's correct.
Edit$_3$: I see now that $P(K^{\complement})$ is missing on LHS in the orange and red branches. and via Edit$_2$ P(K) is missing on LHS of the green one as well.

For (b) I can just use the conditional probability formula $$P(K|C) = \frac{P(K\cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(C | K)P(K)}{P(C)} = \frac{1\cdot 0.5}{0.791} \approx 0.632$$ I use here what I mention above, namely that $P(C | K) = 1$, which I have doubts about, so I hope to get clarified if this is correct.

Not sure the rules are clear. Specifically: what does the $25%$ mean? Do you mean,  conditioned on him not knowing the answer or do you mean that one fourth of the time he doesn't know the answer but he can eliminate one wrong answer?

A numerical example might help.  Suppose there are $64$ questions.  Then he knows $32$ of the answers, leaving $32$ he doesn't know.  The conditional reading would be that he can eliminate an answer in $8$ of those,  the other reading would mean $16$.

@lulu I translated it literally to my best ability, and I think it's a bit vague on purpose. I'd say it's: one fourth of the time he can eliminate one wrong answer, whether he knows or doesn't know the answer, since from what I see, we are not given information that would say something else or?

It needs to be specified and I see no reason to prefer one over the other.  That said,  it's easy enough to do it both ways.

@lulu ok, I'm pretty sure now it's not conditioned on him not knowing the answer. let's assume that one of fourth of the time he can eliminate a wrong answer---do you think what I wrote in the "Edit$_1$" in the post is the correct way to do it? ie using law of total probability twice, at two different "levels" as I describe

Under that assumption,  he gets $\frac N2$ right cause he knows the answer,  then on $\frac N4$ of them he has a $\frac 13$ shot and on the last $\frac N4$ he has a $\frac 14$ shot. Now just multiply and add

@lulu thanks.what if there are questions where he both knows the answer and is able to eliminate an answer? is this adressed in your last answer, or does this possibility immediately imply that they are not independent and we are actually interpreting the problem the other way? or would this be a third interpretation

It's too hard to guess at rules...many combinations are possible.  In this case...well, if he knows the right answer then that means he can eliminate three of the four, so I don't know what it would mean for him to have a special ability to eliminate one.

@lulu I see, many thanks for the help.

There are two ways I am seeing this. The wording is not letting us know which is the right way.

WAY 1 :
Let the test have $80$ questions :
When asked "what is $6+6$ ? (A) 1 , (B) 2 ,  (C) 3 ,  (D) 12" , Jerry has studied enough to know that it is larger than $10$ , hence (D)
This occurs $50\%$ of the time.
That is $40$ question , $40$ marks.
When asked "what is $6+8$ ? (A) Cat , (B) 12 ,  (C) 13 ,  (D) 14" , Jerry has studied enough to know that Cat is not right , hence (A) is eliminated.
Jerry has to guess out of $3$ , hence $1/3$ chance. This occurs $25\%$ of $50\%$ of the time.
That is $10$ question , $10 / 3$ marks.
When asked "what is $8+6$ ? (A) 15 , (B) 12 ,  (C) 13 ,  (D) 14" , Jerry has no idea , hence nothing is eliminated.
Jerry has to guess out of $4$ , hence $1/4$ chance. This occurs $75\%$ of $50\%$ of the time.
That is $30$ question , $30 / 4$ marks.
Over-all marks : $40 + 10/3 + 30/4 = 610/12$
Maximum marks : $80$
Probability is $[610/12]/80 = 0.6354166666666667 \approx 0.6354$
WAY 2 :
Let the test have $80$ questions :
When asked "what is $6+6$ ? (A) 1 , (B) 2 ,  (C) 3 ,  (D) 12" , Jerry has studied enough to know that it is larger than $10$ , hence (D)
This occurs $50\%$ of the time.
That is $40$ question , $40$ marks.
When asked "what is $6+8$ ? (A) Cat , (B) 12 ,  (C) 13 ,  (D) 14" , Jerry has studied enough to know that Cat is not right , hence (A) is eliminated.
Jerry has to guess out of $3$ , hence $1/3$ chance. This occurs $25\%$ of the time.
That is $20$ question , $20 / 3$ marks.
When asked "what is $8+6$ ? (A) 15 , (B) 12 ,  (C) 13 ,  (D) 14" , Jerry has no idea , hence nothing is eliminated.
Jerry has to guess out of $4$ , hence $1/4$ chance. This occurs $25\%$ of the time.
That is $20$ question , $20 / 4$ marks.
Over-all marks : $40 + 20/3 + 20/4 = 620/12$
Maximum marks : $80$
Probability is $[620/12]/80 = 0.6458333333333333 \approx 0.6458$

Using that , we can calculate the conditional probability. That too has two ways.
Way 1 : $40/[610/12] = 0.78688524590163934426229508196721 \approx 0.7869$
Way 2 : $40/[620/12] = 0.77419354838709677419354838709677 \approx 0.7742$
